# Listbox error "Entry is too long for the field"

Tags: abap, dynpro

After selecting a value in a dropdown listbox field, there is this error message:

> Entry is too long for the field

(it's the message number `00092`)

[image]

I created one text field `TXTOPENV` as Listbox with key value, set value using `VRM_SET_VALUES` in PBO section.

Here is the screenshot of screen painter:

[image: screen painter listbox attributes]

Screen flow logic:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE status_0210.
```

ABAP code:

```
DATA txtopenv TYPE c LENGTH 1.

MODULE status_0210 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'ST210'.
  SET TITLEBAR 'T210'.
  PERFORM GetVacancy.
ENDMODULE.

FORM GetVacancy.
  TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_vacancy,
           plans TYPE t528t-plans,
           plstx TYPE t528t-plstx,
         END OF ty_vacancy.
  DATA: wa_vacancy TYPE ty_vacancy.
  LOOP AT it_vacancyid INTO wa_vacancyid.
    SELECT plans plstx
      FROM t528t
      INTO wa_vacancy
      WHERE plans = wa_vacancyid-ty_objid.
    ENDSELECT.
    field_id = wa_vacancy-ty_plans.
    value = wa_vacancy-ty_plstx.
    APPEND value TO values.
    CLEAR wa_vacancy.
  ENDLOOP.

  CALL FUNCTION 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    EXPORTING
      id              = 'TXTOPENV'
      values          = values
    EXCEPTIONS
      id_illegal_name = 1
      OTHERS          = 2.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Your short texts do not look that short after all, do they?

Comment: Show us the code and the field/screen definition...

Comment: It looks like the error message number `092` of type `00` has nothing to do with the function module `VRM_SET_VALUES`. Could you please set the breakpoint on this message while in debugging and send the screenshot of the ABAP and screen stack? You can set such a breakpoint while in New Debugger with the following menu path "Breakpoints -> Breakpoint at -> Breakpoint at message".

Comment: It looks like the length of your `TXTOPENV` in Screen Painter is insufficient, try to set it to 100 or max value it allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Entry is too long for the field" is not specifically related to the listbox fields, but may occur with all types of screen fields, so I will first answer the general case, and then explain why you were mistaken .

The error happens when the screen field is defined with a "definition length" which is larger than the length defined for the eponym global variable in the ABAP program (*eponym: the name has to be the same so that to allow the transfer of values between screen and program, back and forth*), **and** when the input value is larger than the length of the ABAP program.

In your case, the key of the selected value in the listbox is probably larger than 1 character which is the length of the global variable.

**The solution** in your case is to set the variable to 8 characters:

```
DATA txtopenv TYPE t528t-plstx.
```

NB:

- In your screenshot of the listbox field with possible values, only the texts are shown, but you can also display the key value via SAP GUI settings `Interaction Design` > `Visualization 1` > `Show keys within dropdown lists`.